# Converting equations with algebra

Tags: combinatorics

How did my prof go from the 2nd segment to the 3rd segment?

$${n\choose k}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-(k-1))}{k!}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-(k-1))\color{Blue}{(n-k)\cdots2\cdot1}}{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ k! ~~~~~~~~~~\times~~~~~~~~~~ \color{Blue}{(n-k)\cdots2\cdot1}}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} $$

Answer (score 1):

To obtain $n!$ of the numerator you multiply and divide by $(n-k)(n-k-1)(n-k-2)\ldots 3\cdot2\cdot 1$, which is simply $(n-k)!$.